# Is every free additive action on the affine space conjugate to a translation?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Is every free action of the additive group $\mathbb{G}_a$ on the affine space $\mathbb{A}^3$ conjugate to a translation?

In characteristic zero, the answer is yes, and is due to Kaliman. [Kaliman, S. "Free C+-actions on C^3 are translations." Invent. math. 156, 163–173 (2004).] What happens over an algebraically closed field of positive characteristic ?

EDIT: One can of course ask the same question for the affine plane $\mathbb{A}^2$. In characteristic 0, a result of Rentschler [R. Rentschler, Operations du groupe additif sur le plan affine, C.R. Acad. Soc. Paris, 267 (1968), 384-387.] proves that every  $\mathbb{G}_a$ action on $\mathbb{A}^2$ is conjugate to $(x,y)\mapsto (x,y+tq(x))$, for some polynomial $q$. In particular, it is free if and only if it conjugate to a translation. In characteristic $p>0$, a result of Miyanishi [M. Miyanishi "G_a-action of the affine plane", Nagoya Math. J.
Vol. 41 (1971), 97-100] proves that every action is conjugate to $(x,y)\mapsto (x,y+tq_0(x)+t^pq_1(x)+...+t^{p^n}q_n(x))$ for some polynomials $q_1,...,q_n$. In particular, if it is free then it is a conjugate to a translation.

Comment: What's the situation for the affine space $\mathbb{A}^2$?

Comment: Good question. I added the results of Rentschler (car=0) and Miyanishi (car p>0) that settle the case of $\mathbb{A}^2$.

Comment: Thanks. It can be useful to discard any tentative proof that carries over dimension 2.